# Java thread not progressing in a JDBC program

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop, hive

I am trying to find count of rows in all tables of a database on source and destination, source being Greenplum and destination being Hive(on HDFS).
To do the parallel processing, I have created two threads which calls the methods that calculate the counts on both the ends independently. The code can be seen below:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            gpTableCount   = getGpTableCount();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            hiveTableCount = getHiveTableCount();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();

while(!(gpTableCount != null && gpTableCount.size() > 0 && hiveTableCount != null && hiveTableCount.size() > 0)) {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

The results of both the threads are stored in two separate Java Hashmaps.
Below is the count for calculating the GP counts. Method of calculating Hive counts is same except the database name, hence I just gave one method.

```
public Map<String,String> getGpTableCount() throws SQLException {
    Connection gpAnalyticsCon       = (Connection) DbManager.getGpConnection();
    while(keySetIterator_gpTableList.hasNext()) {
        gpTabSchemakey  = keySetIterator_gpTableList.next();
        tablesnSSNs     = gpTabSchemakey.split(",");
        target          = tablesnSSNs[1].split(":");
        analyticsTable  = target[0].split("\\.");   
        gpCountQuery    = "select '" + analyticsTable[1] + "' as TableName, count(*) as Count, source_system_name, max(xx_last_update_tms) from " + tablesnSSNs[0] + " where source_system_name = '" + target[1] + "' group by source_system_name";
        try {
            gp_pstmnt            = gpAnalyticsCon.prepareStatement(gpCountQuery);
            ResultSet gpCountRs  = gp_pstmnt.executeQuery();
            while(gpCountRs.next()) {
                gpCountRs.getLong(2) + ", Max GP Tms: " + gpCountRs.getTimestamp(4).toString());
                gpDataMap.put(gpCountRs.getString(1) + "," + gpCountRs.getString(3), gpCountRs.getLong(2) + "," + gpCountRs.getTimestamp(4).toString());
            }
        } catch(org.postgresql.util.PSQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("GP Connection closed");
    gp_pstmnt.close();
    gpAnalyticsCon.close();
    return gpDataMap;
}
```

Hive's Method:

```
public Map<String, String> getHiveTableCount() throws IOException, SQLException {
    Connection hiveConnection       = DbManager.getHiveConnection();
    while(hiveIterator.hasNext()) {
        gpHiveRec   = hiveIterator.next();
        hiveArray   = gpHiveRec.split(",");
        hiveDetails = hiveArray[1].split(":");
        hiveTable   = hiveDetails[0].split("\\.");
        hiveQuery   = "select '" + hiveTable[1] + "' as TableName, count(*) as Count, source_system_name, max(xx_last_update_tms) from " + hiveDetails[0] + " where source_system_name='" + hiveDetails[1] + "' group by source_system_name";
        try {
            hive_pstmnt             = hiveConnection.prepareStatement(hiveQuery);
            ResultSet hiveCountRs   = hive_pstmnt.executeQuery();
            while(hiveCountRs.next()) {
                hiveDataMap.put(hiveCountRs.getString(1) + "," + hiveCountRs.getString(3), hiveCountRs.getLong(2) + "," + hiveCountRs.getTimestamp(4).toString());
            }
        } catch(HiveSQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return hiveDataMap;
}
```

When the jar is submitted, both the threads are launched and the SQL Queries for GP & Hive start executing simultaneously.
But the problem here is, as soon as the thread for GP finishes the execution of the method: `getGpTableCount()`, I see the print statement: `GP Connection closed` and the hive's thread hangs for atleast 30mins before resuming.
If checked for locks on Hive tables incase there would be none locked. After 30-40mins, the hive threads starts again and finishes. This happens even for  less number of tables (like 20 tables) on hive.

This is how I submit the jar:

```
/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java -Xdebug -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Djava.security.krb5.realm=PROD.COM -Djava.security.krb5.kdc=ip-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false -jar /home/etl/ReconTest/ReconAuto_Test_Prod.jar
```

Could anyone let me know if there is any issue with the way I create threads in the code and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Can you share the `getHiveTableCount()` method body?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `gpTableCount` and `hiveTableCount` are normal `HashMap`s, you're running in to synchronization issues.

This is a broad topic to fully explain here, but here's a short intro:

Since they are populated in different threads, your main thread does not 'see' these changes until the memory is synchronized.  There's no guarantee when this happens (and it's best to assume it will never happen unless you force it).

To do this properly, either use threadsafe versions (see [Collections.synchronizedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) or [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)), or manually synchronize your checks on the same monitor. (i.e. but the check itself in a `synchronized` method, and put the code that populated the map in a synchronized method, too).  Alternatively, you could put the count itself in two `volatile` `int`s, and update those in the other two threads.

Comment: If two threads are trying to access same collection/map object, then there could be a synchronization/lock issue. Here, each thread is having separate collection of its own and no where try to access each others elements. So, is it really synchronization issue ?

Comment: I tried both  Collections.synchronizedMap or ConcurrentHashMap and both didn't work actually.

Comment: There's three threads, not two.  And the third (your main thread) _is_ accessing those maps (more specifically, the `size()` method of it).  I just noticed you also instantiate the maps in your threads, so the vars are initially null.  Meaning most likely your main thread is still seeing the null value. Then even concurrent maps won't help you.  The best way to check for that is to make the variables volatile (not a final solution, but it will rule out that possibility)